# Performance implications using useReducer and context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Are there any performance implications using useReducer with context API with latest version of React? I've stumbled upon an article that states:

*When you use useReducer with Context , a new state value is created when updates are made to state. This leads to the re-rendering of all components that are subscribed to the said context, which is not ideal from a performance and efficiency standpoint.*

However, this performance issue is not mentioned https://react.dev/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context#combining-a-reducer-with-context

Answer (score 1):

It's true that Context API will trigger more function executions because it's going to pass props to every child node of the Provider

Despite this, javascript is fast enough to manage multiple function executions, the thing that is really slow is updating the DOM but React do this after all function executions and optimize it

In conclusion, you have to be aware of this, if it's necessary do performance improvements, but don't let it break your head.